# add glyphicon to accordion card header

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to achieve this

[image]

Using the code from `bootstrap` examples I do it like this

```
<body>
    <!-- create character component -->
    <div id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
        <!-- creation step component -->
        <div class="card">
            <!-- header -->
            <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="headingOne">
                <h5 class="mb-0">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                        Character
                       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    </a>
                </h5>
            </div>
```

But I simply can't add icon to the header. Whether I use it in or out `a` tag it simply shows empty header without arrow.

What is the problem?

Complete code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">

        <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- create character component -->
        <div id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
            <!-- creation step component -->
            <div class="card">
                <!-- header -->
                <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="headingOne">
                    <h5 class="mb-0">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                            Character
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down" aria-hidden="true"></span> 
                        </a>

                    </h5>
                </div>
                <!-- configurable items -->
                <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
                    <div class="card-block">
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Name</td>
                                <td>
                                    <input id="playerName">
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Gender</td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="dropdown">
                                      <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
                                        Dropdown
                                        <span class="caret"></span>
                                      </button>
                                      <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
                                        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                                        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                                      </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Age</td>
                                <td>
                                    <input id="playerAge">
                                <td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Race</td>
                                <td>
                                    <select id="races">
                                        <option>Human</option>
                                        <option>Elf</option>
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>    
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <h3>Character attributes</h3>
        <table>
            <tr><td colspan="2" align="center">Magical traits</td></tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Fire affinity</td>
                <td><input id="fireAffinity"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Earth affinity</td>
                <td><input id="earthAffinity"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Water affinity</td>
                <td><input id="waterAffinity"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Wind affinity</td>
                <td><input id="windAffinity"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Lighting affinity</td>
                <td><input id="lightingAffinity"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr><td colspan="2" align="center">Physical traits</td></tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Power</td>
                <td><input id="physicalPower"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Vitality</td>
                <td><input id="physicalVitality"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td colspan="2" align="center">Mental traits</td></tr>
        </table>

        <h3>Unique traits</h3>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"
                integrity="sha384-3ceskX3iaEnIogmQchP8opvBy3Mi7Ce34nWjpBIwVTHfGYWQS9jwHDVRnpKKHJg7" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.3.7/js/tether.min.js"
                integrity="sha384-XTs3FgkjiBgo8qjEjBk0tGmf3wPrWtA6coPfQDfFEY8AnYJwjalXCiosYRBIBZX8" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"
                integrity="sha384-BLiI7JTZm+JWlgKa0M0kGRpJbF2J8q+qreVrKBC47e3K6BW78kGLrCkeRX6I9RoK" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: working https://jsfiddle.net/4o8wbbuo/ use the following css file: https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css

Comment: @SebastianBrosch Indeed I used this one `https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/css/bootstrap.min.css`. Oddly enough it provides better result. Though in fiddle it works with icons too! (unlike my own `html` file)

Comment: share the complete code

Comment: @SebastianBrosch done (though It is not finished yet as I applied bootstrap only to part of it)

Comment: @SebastianBrosch oh I get it. As they dropped `glyphicons` it does not work anymore (though I wonder why in jsfiddle). But I like the new style better...Hm

Comment: @SebastianBrosch also I was looking for `bootstrap accordion`. No wonder I get `bootstrap 4` edition